# GCC weird linker errors.. works on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, linker

I'm getting this weird linker error using gcc, thought the code works fine when I use Visual Studio..

```
/tmp/ccfcdCxg.o: In function `global constructors keyed to main':
codechef_permut2.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
codechef_permut2.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccfcdCxg.o: In function `ambig(unsigned long)':
codechef_permut2.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
codechef_permut2.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccfcdCxg.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dint post any code, because I think its not required but if someone feels I'll post it.

Comment: In that case, I won't post the answer, because I think it's not required

Comment: Are you linking with `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: Could you please show how the compiler is invoked? There could be linking errors when you compile C++ code with gcc instead of g++.

Comment: Why? The code is unnecessary. The only one thing I think that is needed are maybe parameters for gcc.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- Yes, using `gcc`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that you're using `gcc` rather than `g++` to link your program. `gcc` won't include the C++ library unless you tell it to; `g++` will.

Comment: @questions: It will compile C++; but if you use it to link your program, it won't include the C++ library. In general, you should use `g++` for C++, and `gcc` for C.